# request.session is not saved in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, save, django-sessions

I have a pretty simply utility function that gets an open web order if their is a session key called 'orderId', and will create one if there is no session key, and the parameter 'createIfNotFound' is equal to true in the function. Stepping through it with my debugger I can see that the piece of code that sets the session key after an order has been created does get hit with no exceptions, but when I check the Http request object' session field, it does not have that attribute ?

Utility

```
def get_open_web_order(request, createIfNotFound=False):
    # Check for orderId in session
    order_id = request.session.get('orderId')
    web_order = None

    if None != order_id:
        try:
            web_order = WebOrder.objects.get(id=order_id, status='O')
            logging.info('Found open web order')
        except WebOrder.DoesNotExist:
            logging.info('Web order not found')

    if (None == web_order) and (createIfNotFound == True):
        logging.info('Creating new web order')

        web_order = WebOrder()
        web_order.status = 'O'

        web_order.save()
        request.session['orderId'] = web_order.id

        # Assign logged in user and default billing and shipping
        if request.user.is_authenticated() and hasattr(request.user, 'customer'):
            customer = request.user.customer
            web_order.customer = customer
            web_order.set_defaults_from_customer()
            web_order.save()

    return web_order
```

Comment: This was happening to me with an embedded Shopify app. Safari blocks 3rd party cookies by default, and disabling this feature seemed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In some cases you need to explicitly tell the session that it has been modified.

You can do this by adding `request.session.modified = True` to your view, after changing something in `session`

You can read more on this here - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved

Comment: It's curious this solved the issue, since according to the documentation, the kind of change OP should be detected as session-modifying and trigger a save, so an explicit set of the `.modified` attribute should not be needed. Regardless, I'm running into a similar issue, and will update if this fixes my issue as well.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, turns out I had set `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` in settings.py to the incorrect domain so it would not save any of my new session data. If you are using `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN`, try checking that!

For example, if I am running the server on my localhost but I have in my settings `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = "notlocalhost"`, then nothing I change in `request.session` will save.

Answer (score 0):

For example, putting `request.session.modified = True` (`False` by default) anywhere in `test()` can save session as shown below. *Session is automatically saved only when top-level key's data is modified and you can see [When sessions are saved](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved) and you can see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76631780/why-is-session-unexpectedly-saved-in-django) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76631780/why-is-session-unexpectedly-saved-in-django/76641365#76641365) explaining when and where session is saved:

```py
# "veiws.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
    request.session.modified = True # Here
    return HttpResponse('Test')
```

Or, setting [SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#session-save-every-request) `True` in `settings.py` as shown below also can save session:

```py
# "settings.py"

SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
```