# Why is session unexpectedly saved in Django?

Tags: python, django, session, save, django-sessions

I could properly experiment when session is and isn't saved in Django as shown in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76622009/how-to-experiment-when-session-is-and-isnt-saved-in-django/76630505#76630505) referring [When sessions are saved](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved). *I use **Django 4.2.3**.

But if I run all cases together as shown below (The 1st run):

```py
# "views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
    
    # The 1st case
    request.session["foo"] = "bar"
    
    # The 2nd case
    del request.session["foo"]

    # The 3rd case
    request.session["foo"] = {}

    # The 4th case
    request.session["foo"]["bar"] = "baz"

    return HttpResponse('Test')
```

Then, the 4th case is unexpectedly saved as shown below (The 2nd run):

```py
# "views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
    print(request.session.get('foo')) # {'bar': 'baz'}
    return HttpResponse('Test')
```

Because if I run the 1st, 2nd and 3rd cases together except the 4th case as shown below (The 1st run):

```py
# "views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
    
    # The 1st case
    request.session["foo"] = "bar"
    
    # The 2nd case
    del request.session["foo"]

    # The 3rd case
    request.session["foo"] = {}

    return HttpResponse('Test')
```

Then, run only the 4th case as shown below (The 2nd run):

```py
# "views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):

    # The 4th case
    request.session["foo"]["bar"] = "baz"

    return HttpResponse('Test')
```

Then, the 4th case is not saved as shown below (The 3rd run):

```py
# "views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
    print(request.session.get('foo')) # {}
    return HttpResponse('Test')
```

Actually, I don't use the code below in the code above as you can see:

```py
request.session.modified = True
```

And, I set [SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#session-save-every-request) `False` in `settings.py` as shown below:

```py
# "settings.py"

SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = False
```

So, why is the 4th case unexpectedly saved if I run all cases together?

Comment: I would indeed expect that Django does not save the fourth one, especially since it does not even know the subitem was saved. Question: how did you check/test when the request is saved, that seems to be the missing point here.

Comment: If you for example use memory as "session storage", there is not really something that is "saved", it just remains in memory. So some backends don't really have a "save" mechanism to begin with.

Comment: @Willem_VO_supports_mod_strike I think the 4th case will be saved to `django_session` table in database.

Comment: @SupKaiKazuyaIto: so it was saved? I can't reproduce that, or at least not with `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST` set to `False` etc.

Comment: When you do `request.session["foo"] = {}` (3rd case) the session is altered and will be saved. Then you do `request.session["foo"]["bar"] = "baz"` (4th case) and since you do it before the session is saved this data will be part of the session too.

Comment: @Matthias: ah, I think that the session is saved at the end, if `request.session.modified = True`, so if you don't set `request.session['foo'] = {}` in the *same* request, then it will not save.

Comment: Djangos middleware deals with `request.session.modified` during the response. In other words: the session is saved when the response is done, not every time when `request.session`  is altered. You can find the code in django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this saves is because Django does not *immediately* saves changes to the session variables.

during the response, it will check if `request.modified` is set to `True` (or just save anyway in case `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST` is set to `True`). This means that it will serialize the session at the state of that moment, and save it in the backend you picked.

This thus means that if something "triggered" the `request.session` to believe that it has been modified, it will save the *final* state, regardless whether the last modification of the object triggered the session modification "indicator". So it can sometimes "piggyback" on modifications that have been made.

This means that if we have two views:

```
def view1(request):
    request.session['foo'] = {}
    return HttpResponse('response1')


def view2(request):
    request.session.get('foo', {})['bar'] = 42
    return HttpResponse('response2')
```

we can first trigger `view1` and at the end, it will indicate the sessions have been modified, and save it. If we then make a request to `view2` it will *not* update, since updating `request.session['foo']['bar'] = 42` indeed does not trigger the session object that it is modified, and if during the response `request.session.modified` is still `False` so it will not update.

In short you thus can see the sessions as some sort of proxy-object. When you need it, it will retrieve it from the database and deserialize it. During the response, it will see if it has been modified (in a manner that the session object detected), and save the updated object once to the database.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st case makes [request.session.modified](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2584783f46922bcb456ceb9700a3726314df65d3/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py#L46) `True` (`False` by default), then the session is saved in [process_response()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/7eeadc82c2f7d7a778e3bb43c34d642e6275dacf/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py#L12C7-L12C24) in [SessionMiddleware class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/7eeadc82c2f7d7a778e3bb43c34d642e6275dacf/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py#L12C7-L12C24) after completing `test()`. That's why the 4th case is unexpectedly saved. *All cases except the 4th case can make `request.session.modified` `True` and you can see [When sessions are saved](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved):

```py
# "views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
    
    print(request.session.modified) # False

    # The 1st case
    request.session["foo"] = "bar"

    print(request.session.modified) # True
    
    # The 2nd case
    del request.session["foo"]

    # The 3rd case
    request.session["foo"] = {}

    # The 4th case
    request.session["foo"]["bar"] = "baz"

    return HttpResponse('Test')
```